# Is this declaration of ODBC driver correct?

Tags: java, odbc, ms-access-2010, ucanaccess, jdbc-odbc

```
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        //System.out.println("Driver loaded");
        String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+path;
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

I don't get any error or bugs & doesn't connect!?

Comment: Your question is **vague**. There might be situation in setting up the **dsn** or many other things. You must catch up this link:http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/SimpleexampleofJDBCODBCfunctionality.htm and this link:https://www.javatpoint.com/connectivity-with-access-without-dsn for more details

Comment: UCanAccess is not an ODBC based driver; your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example how to use it: http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/jdbc/

The driver was removed in Oracle JRE 8, so use Java version 7 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

UCanAccess is a JDBC driver in its own right. It does not use ODBC, so

```java
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

is not applicable. That is the JDBC-ODBC Bridge, which was removed from Java 8.

For details on how to use UCanAccess, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/2144390).

Answer (score -1):

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+path;
Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection(url);  
Statement st=c.createStatement();   
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from table");
```